# Как получить текст из виджетов в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Вопрос такой, было ПО, решил расширить и добавить в него простой интерфейс. Для этого использовал PyQt5 + Qt Designer. Но не могу связать с переменными в коде значения, которые вводятся в виджете `LineEdit`, пример ниже.

Есть диалоговое окно, на нём пустые виджеты `LineEdit` для ввода данных и кнопка для запуска расчётов.
Код для связи кнопки и кода:

```python
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

Form, _ = uic.loadUiType("1.ui") 


class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog, Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ResultButtonPressed) 

    @staticmethod
    def ResultButtonPressed():
        a = input() 
        b = input() 
        c = input() 
        v = a + b - c
        print(v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui() 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Нужно присвоить значения, введённые в полях виджета `LineEdit` (`lineEdit_1`, `lineEdit_2`, `lineEdit_3`) переменным в функции (`a`, `b`, `c`) при нажатии кнопки. Как это сделать?

Comment: Arti, на ваш вопрос вам дали ответ - нужно использовать `self.lineEdit_1.text()`.  Не забудьте пометить ответ как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие проблемы- задайте новый вопрос.  Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему в будущем.  Чтобы получать реальную ошибку - всегда запускайте свое приложение в терминале/колсоли/CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если каждый `LineEdit` в QtDesigner именуется именно так  (`lineEdit_1`, `lineEdit_2`, `lineEdit_3`), то в коде методов класса, к которому подключён UI, к ним можно обратиться как `self.lineEdit_1`, `self.lineEdit_2`, `self.lineEdit_3` соответственно.

Теперь можно пользоваться методами, указанными в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html). В данном случае нужен `.text()`:

```python
def ResultButtonPressed():
    a = int(self.lineEdit_1.text())
    b = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
    c = int(self.lineEdit_3.text())
    print(a + b - c)
```

*Примечание*: по указанной ссылке содержится документация для Qt на языке C++, но все названия методов и их описания будут работать и для PyQt5.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение и отдельно за документацию, буду пробовать

Comment: Рад помочь. Если вопрос для вас закрыт, ответ можно отметить как решение.

Comment: Кстати, если вам нужно сделать вывод в отдельном окне, то можно использовать это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431889/Как-перейти-в-другой-класс-при-определённых-действиях-в-pyqt5/1432076#1432076 . Но на будущее: в одном вопросе лучше задавать один вопрос.

Comment: Проверил данный вариант, код просто завершается без вывода результатов

Comment: Вы ведь добавили `print`? В моём примере был только ввод.

Comment: Разумеется)) выдаёт process finished with exit code -1073740791

Comment: А к `int` приводили? Должно работать.

Comment: Да, задам данный вопрос в отдельной теме